# force:recordData simpleRecord returning null

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="recordHandler"
    recordId="{v.recordId}"
    layoutType="FULL"
    fields="Install_At__c"  
    targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
    Mode = "EDIT" 
    recordUpdated="{!c.createRecord}"                  
    />
```

Handler

```
    ({

  createRecord: function(component, event, helper, sObjectRecord) {



  var simpleRecord = component.get("v.simpleRecord.Install_At__c");

   console.log('  this is the simpleRecord ' + simpleRecord);

       //Calling CreateRecord modal providing recordTypeId
        helper.createDemoRequestForm(component, "012a0000001RJft", "Demo_Request__c"); 

  },

     /*
     * closing quickAction modal window
     * */
    closeModal : function(component, event, helper){
       helper.closeModal();
    }

})
```

helper

```
   ({
   createDemoRequestForm : function(component, recordTypeId, entityApiName) {  

       var createDemoRequestFormEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createDemoRequestFormEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": entityApiName,
            "RecordTypeId": recordTypeId,
            "defaultFieldValues": {
                "Opportunity__c" : component.get("v.recordId"),
                "Account_Address__c" : component.get("v.simpleRecord.Install_At__c")

            }
});
         createDemoRequestFormEvent.fire();

    },


    closeModal : function(){
        var closeEvent = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        if(closeEvent){
        closeEvent.fire();
        } else{

            alert('force:closeQuickAction event is not supported in this Ligthning Context');

        }

    },


})
```

So this is very basic, and i do plan on expanding it (hence having both the handler and controller).

But right now i can't even get one field value to pass the the createRecord Modal. The recordId value passes fine, but anything from the simpleRecord completely flops. Whenever i try to log it using either

```
console.log('SIMPLERECORD TYPE IS: ' + JSON.stringify(component.get("v.simpleRecord.Install_At__c));


console.log('SIMPLERECORD TYPE IS: ' + component.get("v.simpleRecord.Install_At__c);

or even

var simpleRecord = component.get("v.simpleRecord.Install_At__c");
console.log(' test tes  ' + simpleRecord);
```

It's always null and the param is never passed.

Comment: Where are you placing this component?

Comment: @SebastianKessel as a quick action on the opportunity page.